# Creating Projection/Datum TransvMerc/OrdSurvGrtBrit in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I have Memory Map files QCT exported to ECW.

The Projection/Datum is Transverse Mercator / Ordnance Survey Great Britain which is not mentioned in the list of Projections/Datums available.

How can I create it from the scratch or by modifying any available?

Comment: Try epsg:27700 which is the usual code for osgb